# how to convert CIFilter output to CMSampleBuffer

Tags: swift, cvpixelbuffer, cmsamplebuffer

I want to add some filter to `CMSampleBuffer` using `CIFilter`, then convert it back to `CMSampleBuffer`

I have some filter like this:

```
let filter = YUCIHighPassSkinSmoothing()
    filter.inputImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBufferFromCMSampleBuffer)
    filter.inputAmount = 0.8
    if let output = filter.outputImage{
    }
```

Note that I tried to get pixelBuffer using `output.pixelBuffer` but it always return nil

I tried to create pixcel buffer like this:

```
extension CIImage{
func toCVPixelBuffer() -> CVPixelBuffer? {
      let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary
      var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
      let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(self.extent.width), Int(self.extent.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, attrs, &pixelBuffer)

      guard (status == kCVReturnSuccess) else {
          return nil
      }

      return pixelBuffer
  }
}

-> let newPixelBuffer = output.toCVPixelBuffer()
```

But it seem only create empty pixel buffer and need to fill the current CIImage into this using `context.render` method like this:

`self.cIContext.render(newCiImage, to: buffer)`

But I dont want to using this because it's took a lot of CPU, can anyone give me some advices? Thanks so much